# Fform method returns a blank page

Tags: laravel-5

I want my admin user to be able to approve a jobpost
so I defined a method in my jobposts controller like this:

```
 public function approved(Request $request, JobPost $jobpost)
{
    //save
    $approved = JobPost::where('id', $jobpost->id)->update([
        'approval'=> $request->input('approved')
        ]);

    if($approved)
    {     $user = auth()->user();
        $jobposts = auth()->user()->JobPosts;
        $company = auth()->user()->company;
       return view('/JobPosts/admin/WaitingJobPosts',[
           'jobposts' => $jobposts,
           'company' => $company,
           'user' => $user,
       ]);
    }
```

Then I defined a rout for it in my web.php:

```
Route::patch('jobposts.approval/approved', [
    'as'=>'jobposts.approved',
    'uses'=> 'JobPostsController@approved'
]);
```

and in my view I have defined a form like this:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('jobposts.approved', [$jobpost-> id])}}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
                                <input type="hidden" name="approved" value="1">
                            {{--<form method="post" action="{{route('jobposts.approved', [$jobpost])}}">--}}
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{--<input type="hidden" value="1" name="approval"/>--}}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">تایید</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

It returns a blank page and does not change the approval column value for the job post. The returned url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobposts.approval/approved?
3
I'm a bit new to laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a response in your `approved` action in case approving fails so you need to return a view or some sort of response.

Also, `return view('/JobPosts/admin/WaitingJobPosts'...` seems incorrect since you have to provide a view in dot notation in Laravel and not the actual path to the view.

You are type-hinting a job post so there is no need to run a find query. You can simply work with the `$jobpost` variable.

Second, your route seems incorrect. Change it as follows

```
Route::patch('jobposts/{job_post}/approved', 'JobPostsController@approved')->name('jobposts.approved');
```

Finally, here is the form.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('jobposts.approved', ['job_post' => $jobpost])}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="approved" value="1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">تایید</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i did that it still returns a blank page with the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobposts/3/approved
and does not change the approval value